# What are shipyard sponsors?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

Shipyards can have five sponsors.  I assume this means the sponsor planets are contributing production to the shipyard?  If so, how can I tell how much they are contributing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean **shipyards**, not starbases. Or this is a starbase feature I've not yet discovered.

If you go to the shipyard, select it, and click "Manage" (or doubleclick on it), there's a "Edit sponsors" button on the bottom left.

Below the name of the planet, there's some numbers. I forget what they all are, but the second-to-last number indicates the tile distance between the planet and the shipyard (which is relevant as production decays more over longer distances), and the last number indicates the resulting production the planet would add to the shipyard.

This is the result in production, so the number will be affected by you changing things like production focus or social/military production division on the planet.

**Edit**

From memory, the line of numbers is something like:

(icon) **3.0** / **6.0** (icon) **15** (icon) **2.6**

In order:

**3.0** / **6.0** means the planet is generating **6** production, with a 50% split to military production (meaning **3** of its production goes to military projects)

**15** is the tile distance to the shipyard.

Given how the shipyard is 15 tiles removed from the planet, the **3** production it sends will be cut down to **2.6** because of the distance decay.

Comment: Fixed my post to reference shipyards.  Okay, so the values are production over distance!  Now this is starting to make sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @MadMAxJr I just updated my answer somewhat to reflect the meaning of all numbers and how they relate to one another. This is from memory though, so I might be a bit off on the position of the numbers. Hovering over them will reveal their meaning in the menu itself though.